# How to prevent VS Code from auto-tabbing to browser while running nodemon?

Tags: reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code, nodemon

So I'm working with React for the first time and for some reason when nodemon is running and I'm editting code, whenever I type anything, VS code automatically tabs over to the browser which is obviously not the behavior I want. I've used nodemon before but never noticed this and it's pretty disruptive. Not sure exactly if this is the issue, but is there any way to prevent VS code/nodemon from auto-tabbing to browser upon change detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `Browser=none` in your start script

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "BROWSER=none react-scripts start"
},
```

The browser is getting opened by default `create-react-app` config, every time nodemon restarts that process it opens the browser. Though you shouldn't need to use nodemon here anyways because react detects changes on its own to refresh the opened instance.

ref: https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/stop-create-react-app-from-opening-a-browser-window-on-start

Comment: Thanks @Danyal! I actually did realize that nodemon was unnecessary eventually but I figured that there was a setting somewhere, too. I also had a hunch that create-react-app was part of what was happening. Cool got it!